# NextJS strange behaviour after reinstalling Mac OS

Tags: next.js

I have working nextjs app (12.1.0) until for some reasons I need to reinstall my Mac Mini M1 (Ventura 13.4.1). After reinstalling I do these:

1. Install NVM and install and use node v16 (which I used before)
2. Install yarn
3. `yarn dev` and `yarn build` then `yarn start` works fine

But, I found strange behaviour: images didn't showed up inconsistently. I looked up at Sources:
[image]
while I check on source code there is actual image.

Please help, what should I do to fix this?